# Erro ao editar dados de ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

Em projeto possuo um ViewModel e dentro dele meus models e tudo mais. O que acontece é que eu estou tentando editar os dados que já estão salvos no banco.

Consigo trazer os dados editados da view, mas ao realmente salvar, esse erro é gerado:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateConcurrencyException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=472540 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.

Eu não sei o que posso estar fazendo de errado na hora de editar e salvar esses dados...

Pois bem, a action POST que faz a edição desses dados, tem o seguinte código:

```
         [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(AnamineseViewModel anamneseViewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            AnaAnamineseAlimentar anamnese = db.AnaAnamineseAlimentar.Find(anamneseViewModel.AnaAnamineseAlimentar.AnaId);
            CliCliente cliente = db.CliCliente.Find(anamneseViewModel.CliCliente.CliId);
            RecRecordatorio recordatorio = db.RecRecordatorio.Find(anamneseViewModel.RecRecordatorio.AnaId);
            List<RefRefeicao> refeicao = anamneseViewModel.RefRefeicao;
            List<QfaQuestionarioFrequenciaAlimentar> qfa = anamneseViewModel.QfaQuestionarioFrequenciaAlimentar;

            cliente = anamneseViewModel.CliCliente;
            anamnese = anamneseViewModel.AnaAnamineseAlimentar;
            recordatorio = anamneseViewModel.RecRecordatorio;
            refeicao = anamneseViewModel.RefRefeicao;
            qfa = anamneseViewModel.QfaQuestionarioFrequenciaAlimentar;

            var cliCliente = db.Set<CliCliente>().Local.FirstOrDefault(f => f.CliId == anamneseViewModel.CliCliente.CliId);

            if (cliCliente != null)
            {
                db.Entry(cliCliente).State = EntityState.Detached;
            }

            db.Entry(cliente).State = EntityState.Modified;

            var anaAnamnese = db.Set<AnaAnamineseAlimentar>().Local.FirstOrDefault(f => f.AnaId == anamneseViewModel.AnaAnamineseAlimentar.AnaId);

            if (anaAnamnese != null)
            {
                db.Entry(anaAnamnese).State = EntityState.Detached;
            }

            db.Entry(anamnese).State = EntityState.Modified;

            var recrecordatorio = db.Set<RecRecordatorio>().Local.FirstOrDefault(f => f.AnaId == anamneseViewModel.RecRecordatorio.AnaId);

            if (recrecordatorio != null)
            {
                db.Entry(recrecordatorio).State = EntityState.Detached;
            }

            db.Entry(recordatorio).State = EntityState.Modified;

            for (int i = 0; i < refeicao.Count; i++)
            {
                var refRefeicao = db.Set<RefRefeicao>().Local.FirstOrDefault(f => f.RefId == anamneseViewModel.RefRefeicao[i].RefId);

                if (refRefeicao != null)
                {
                    db.Entry(refRefeicao).State = EntityState.Detached;
                }

                db.Entry(refeicao[i]).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < qfa.Count; i++)
            {
                var qfaQfa = db.Set<QfaQuestionarioFrequenciaAlimentar>().Local.FirstOrDefault(f => f.QfaId == anamneseViewModel.QfaQuestionarioFrequenciaAlimentar[i].QfaId);

                if (qfaQfa != null)
                {
                    db.Entry(qfaQfa).State = EntityState.Detached;
                }

                db.Entry(qfa[i]).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }

            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(anamneseViewModel);
    }
```

Eu consigo retornar os dados, mas no `db.SaveChanges()` o erro é gerado.. Como que eu poderia resolver?

Comment: Já verificou se `anamneseViewModel` não está nula?

Comment: Já... Não está nula... Ela é preenchida completamente...

Comment: Parece que você está editando várias entidades que estão correlacionadas, e a atualização de uma reflete em cascata nas demais, já tentou dar um savechange individual em cada uma para ver se executa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu resolvi o erro.

Ele era gerado pelo fato de na hora de salvar, eu não estar com os Ids, tanto da tabela, como dos relacionamentos entre as entidades.

Como não havia referencia, o erro era gerado.

Para resolver, eu ajustei a view e nela, passo os Ids correspondentes.